# STS ,SAML and Java SDK Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am trying to get temp credentials for AWS from STS using a SAML requet(from ADFS).
I have the SAML token, the role arn and principalARN. If I use this to login using AWS CLI they work. But using the same 3 with the Java SDK gives the following error.

> Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain

Here is the Java code I am using.

```
AssumeRoleWithSAMLRequest samlreq =new AssumeRoleWithSAMLRequest().withPrincipalArn(principalARN).withRoleArn(roleARN).withSAMLAssertion(SAMLToken);

AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient stsclient = new AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient();

AssumeRoleWithSAMLResult tempcreds=stsclient.assumeRoleWithSAML(samlreq);
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong or missing?

Here is the Stack trace:

> Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable
>   to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain    at
>   com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:117)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.invoke(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:1098)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.assumeRoleWithSAML(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:575)
>     at App.main(App.java:83)

Comment: Can you include the exact stack trace you are seeing?

Comment: I have added the stack trace in the questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it working finally had to add :

```
BasicAWSCredentials basicCreds=new BasicAWSCredentials("", "");
AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient stsclient = new AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient(basicCreds);
```

Basically give the sts client a blank set of credentials.

Comment: Same issue and fix for .Net SDK.

Answer (score 1):

The AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient is deprecated.  The following code also works.

```
BasicAWSCredentials theAWSCredentials= new BasicAWSCredentials("","");
AWSCredentialsProvider theAWSCredentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(theAWSCredentials);
AWSSecurityTokenService theSecurityTokenService = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(theAWSCredentialsProvider).build();
```

Comment: AWSBasicCredentials on AWS-SDK-JAVA-V2.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Access key ID cannot be blank.... you would be better off just using the AnonymousCredentialsProvider, i.e: `cognitoIdentityBuilder.region(AWSREGION).credentialsProvider(AnonymousCredentialsProvider.create());`